# Rails - failing to set open graph url correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am developing a Rails application and I wish to use the open graph protocol so that on the "articles" page perople can link to social media (facebook, twitter, and google+) to recommend/like etc the article.

As part of the this I endevour, unsuccessfully to set og metatags for the url, within the head section of the page.  From the code partial ogmeta.html.erb

```
<meta property="og:title" content='<%= meta[:title] || "DrillInvestor" %>'>
<meta property="og:type" content='<%= meta[:type] || "website" %>'>
<meta property="og:image" content='<%= meta[:image] || "http://www.whatever.com/image.jpg" %>'>
<meta property="og:url" content='<%= meta[:url] || "post_url(@post)" %>'>
```

Which when I view the page source I see

```
<html>
   <head>  
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>  
   <meta property="og:title" content='DrillInvestor'>
   <meta property="og:type" content='website'>
   <meta property="og:image" content='http://www.whatever.com/image.jpg'>

   <meta property="og:url" content='post_url(@post)'>
```

What I am trying to pass as the url I can see from a print statement in the posts controller

```
puts "==================="
puts "url = " + post_url(@post).to_s
```

I see url = http://quiet-fortress-3338.herokuapp.com/posts/drill-01-more-updates which is what I am want, in this case, to see as the og:url.

I am a recovering COBOL pogrammer and sometimes (well perhaps more than that) lose my way with this sort of stuff.
If I hardcode the og:url I get the appropriate page.  I have tried a numer of dfferent things including#{} enclosing the post_url(@post) etc.
Thanks in advance and any help welcome
Pierre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get rid of the quotes around `"post_url(@post)"`. Just change it to `post_url(@post)`. Note that in your print statement you don't have it enclosed in quotes and it works.

As an aside, you don't need to call `to_s` in either case - `post_url(@post)` returns a string.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.  When I remove the quotes e.g. <meta property="og:url" content='<%= meta[:url] || post_url(@post) %>'> I get runtime syntax error "unknown regexp options - dvlpr"

Comment: Yikes. You could try using double quotes around the erbs, e.g., `<meta property="og:url" content="<%= meta[:url] || post_url(@post) %>">`.

Comment: I got it to work removing the quotes but then if I go to any other screen (e.g. NOT post) I get "No route matches {:id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]"

Comment: That's because `post_url(@post)` is Rails shorthand for 'return a string representing the url/route to the `show` action on the `Post` controller, with an `:id` parameter set to the `id` of the `@post` object'. This error is telling you that in whatever other view you were using, no `@post` object was passed to that view, so the value of its `id` is nil.

Comment: To clarify that a bit, if the `id` of the record represented by your `@post` object is 1, `post_url(@post)` returns the string, "h ttp://www.mydomain.com/posts/1".

Comment: I put the og:url within an if statement which I think may work.   Steve I apprecaite your time and effort and am accepting your answer - Pierre